# Использование std::begin и std::end с указателями

Tags: c++

Хочу суммировать значения элементов перечислителя, использую стандартные функции std::begin и std::end. Знаю, что перечислители не очень подходят для этой задачи, но захотелось поэкспериментировать, при этом используя std::begin и std::end.

Следующий код работает корректно:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

enum ItemType {
    health_potion = 3,
    torches = 6,
    arrows = 12
};

int main()
{
    ItemType my_item[3]{health_potion,torches,arrows};
    int count = 0;

    for (auto it = std::begin(my_item); it != std::end(my_item); ++it) {

        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        count += *it;
    }
    std::cout << "Count=" << count << std::endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

А этот нет, да и понятно почему: для указателей стандартные функции std::begin и std::end не определены.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

enum ItemType {
    health_potion = 3,
    torches = 6,
    arrows = 12
};
void countTotalItems(const ItemType *my_type);


int main()
{
    ItemType my_item[3]{health_potion,torches,arrows};
    countTotalItems(my_item);

    return 0;
}

void countTotalItems(const ItemType *my_type) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (auto it = std::begin(my_type); it != std::end(my_type+i); ++it) {
        ++i;
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        count += *it;
    }
    std::cout << "Count=" << count << std::endl;
}
```

*Ошибка:    "E0304  отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "std::begin" и "std::end", соответствующие списку аргументов"*

Можно ли как-нибудь определить эту функцию по-другому, чтобы она работала?

Comment: Как в стандартной библиотеке — с использованием двух итераторов, *каковыми указатели по сути и являются*, для определения начала и конца диапазона. Вы, как бы сказать... пытаетесь найти начало начала — ведь указатель и есть итератор для массива, так что вы ищете что-то вроде `begin(begin(my_item))`.

Comment: Указатель не хранит размер данных. Вы используете std::begin/std::end как будто это какой то каст.

Comment: Не понимаю, как корректно написать :(

Comment: принимайте пару указателей: `countTotalItems(std::begin(my_item),std::end(my_item));`